# CSS Transition Timing Function doesn't reset gallery

Tags: css, wordpress, transition, elementor

On my Elementor webpage (https://www.velthuisweb.nl/rr/) you'll find an image caroussel at the top.
This image caroussel is using a css transition-timing-function: linear to smooth out the behaviour of the gallery.

After the last image is being displayed, the whole gallery becomes empty (instead of adding the first image after the last image).

How do I achieve this the best way so my gallery will continously show images?

Screenshot:
https://imgur.com/a/avhtrz1

Code:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
 selector .swiper-slide {
    width: fit-content !important;
display: inline-flex !important;
}
    selector .swiper-wrapper {
    column-gap: 5px;
}
selector .swiper-slide-image {
    transition-timing-function: linear !important;
    height: 600px;
}
selector .swiper-wrapper{
-webkit-transition-timing-function: linear !important;
transition-timing-function: linear !important;
}
selector {
    position : relative !important;
    transition-timing-function: linear !important;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear !important;
    pointer-events: none !important
}
}
```

Comment: https://verpex.com/blog/website-tips/how-to-create-a-css-only-infinite-scroll-animation

Comment: I mentioned that I'm using Elementor. Therefore I'm not as flexible to use any of the custom code provided @CBroe

Comment: Doesn't change the fact, that you will have to implement a solution that follows a similar _principle_, if you want a CSS-only solution. You can not have one single element (the slider wrapper) move out one side of the viewport, and then expect to see its "other end" appear at the other side of the viewport again - that is not how things work. Therefor this _needs_ a solution, that moves the individual slides "to the back of the queue", once they are out of view.